# Rotating a Reference Frame by another Reference Frame

Tags: geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotations, programming

I have a coordinate system defined by the unit vectors **X** = (1,0,0) and **Y** = (0,1,0).

I then have a reference frame defined by the orthogonal unit vectors **P** and **Q**.  **PQ** describes a plane that is offset from the **XY** coordinate system (The plane is rotated and inclined).

Then, I have *another* reference frame, **I** and **J**.  **IJ** describe a frame that is offset from **PQ**.  **IJ** treats **PQ** as its "parent" frame, in the same way that **PQ** treats **XY** as its "parent" frame.

I need to produce a pair of vectors that describe **I** and **J** as they relate to the absolute reference frame, **X** and **Y**.

In fact, I need to be able to produce vectors describing reference frames of *any* level of depth.  That is, I could have the reference frame **AB**, which is offset from **IJ**, which is offset from **PQ**, which is offset from **XY** - and so forth.

At first, I thought that simply summing and normalizing the series of parent vectors preceding the reference frame in question would do the trick, but it seems to be producing odd results.

For what it's worth (if you can't already tell), I am a programmer, not a mathematician.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do your three coordinate systems share a common origin?  Also you do not describe a third axis e.g. $\mathbf Z$.  Is it safe to assume that $\mathbf Z$ is defined by right-hand coordinate system convention?

Comment: Also, if you posted the relevant portion of your code, that might help.

Comment: @Tpofofn - yes, all the coordinate systems are of a common origin.  The third axis in each system is orthogonal to the other two - so in the example where **X** = 1,0,0, **Y** = 0,1,0, then **Z** would equal 0,0,1.

The code I'm afraid would be more confusing than it's worth.  It's caught up with the six orbital elements, and calculating perifocal vectors therefrom.  It would require more explanation than the OP, I think.

Comment: Are $\mathbf P$, $\mathbf Q$ perpendicular?  Are $\mathbf I$, $\mathbf J$ perpendicular?